# SQL vs NOSQL : Explanation for few points

Tags: sql, nosql

After reading more than 100 documents on SQL vs NOSQL, I still have two questions.

1). How latency of NoSQL DB is better than SQL DB?

2). How NoSQL DB's are auto scalable?

3). How NoSQL DB stores large data than SQL DB?

On every website , it says, NoSQL are having low latency, can handle large data and are auto-scalable. But no one explains how?

Looking for explained answers.

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _I still have two questions._ Pardon me, but it looks like you still have **three** questions.

Answer (score 3):

**1) How latency of NoSQL DB is better than SQL DB?**

In SQL databases, consistency is prioritized. As consistency is prioritized, the database manage system has to do lots of work to maintain the consistent state, which will definitely compromise the performance. In contrast, NoSQL databases have less constraints than SQL by reducing the overhead of consistency.

**2) How NoSQL DB's are auto scalable?**

SQL databases are vertically scalable, You're able to increase the load on a single server by adding more CPU, RAM, or SSD capacity. NoSQL databases are horizontally scalable. You’re able to handle higher traffic by adding more servers to your NoSQL database.

**3) How NoSQL DB stores large data than SQL DB?**

NoSQL systems are distributed, non-relational databases designed for large-scale data storage.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing NoSQL on a single server requires more CPU resources due to the complexity of the queries. If you move to a **NoSQL database** on a **single server** **without distributing** the data, make sure you handle a higher CPU load and RAM usage.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Databases:

Suitable for business domains where transactional consistency (ACID properties) is essential, such as reservation systems (e.g., for trains, flights, movies) or finance-related projects like banking systems.
Transactions in these domains require guarantees of data integrity and consistency, and users are willing to wait for these assurances.
SQL databases provide a structured schema and are well-suited for complex queries and joins.

NoSQL Databases:

Suited for business domains focused on content management and scalability, where fast response times and horizontal scalability are prioritized.
Examples include movie streaming platforms, blogs, social media platforms, and other applications requiring flexible and scalable storage solutions.
NoSQL databases offer schema flexibility and are designed for horizontal scalability, making them suitable for handling large volumes of unstructured or semi-structured data.

Comment: Pardon me, but it looks like you copied text from somewhere and pasted it here. Besides, it doesn't look, to me, like you answered the actual questions that were posted, for example how does your answer address this question: _How NoSQL DB's are auto scalable?_